# Tensorflow program results in type conversion error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Tring to master Tensorflow, following documentation of TensorFlow.

**Below program results in 'Incompatible type conversion error'**

```
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-3], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = 1.0
linear_model = W * x + b
#tf.to_float(linear_model, name='ToFloat')

# Global initialization is must
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(linear_model, {x:[1,2,3,4]}))
```

**Above program results in this error**

> File "v-prog3-variables.py", line 7, in 
>       linear_model = W * x + b
>   .. .. ..
>   ValueError: Incompatible type conversion requested to type 'float32'
>   for variable of type 'int32_ref'

**I tried to solve the problem by defining the 'linear_model' variable as float (linear_model = 1.0) or tf.to_float(linear_model = W * x + b)**

but nothing works

Im a TensorFlow newbie, please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to run by recasting it to float32.  Have you read the source code of the library?  Yea... I don't ask questions lol

```
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-3], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = W * x + tf.cast(b, tf.float32)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(linear_model, {x:[1,2,3,4]}))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a named argument for the type, e.g. `tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)`

The signature of `tf.Variable` is `__init__(self, initial_value=None, trainable=True,...` leading to common errors.

The `__init__` method will then infer type from your inputs:

- `[.3]` will give a `tf.float32`, and
- `[-3]` will give a `tf.int32`
  leading to the error you got when you multiply them.

If you want to stick with the `tf.float32` type, you could also use `[-3.]` as initial value for `b`.